# How do I test a paragraph bundle entity reference with Behat?

Tags: 8, testing

I am learning Behat with Drupal 8 and I'm stuck on trying to test a paragraph bundle (`field_related_content`) which has a title and description field, the title is an entity reference field to content type `marine_notices`. Currently I have the below, but the results are 'No link to Post Title', am I missing something?

```
  @api
  Scenario: Reference site pages from within a "marine_notices" node
  Given "marine_notices" content:
    | title      |
    | Post title  |
  When I am viewing a "marine_notices" content:
    | title                | Post title         |
    | field_related_content | Post title - <front> |
  Then I should see the link "Post title"
```

Comment: That won't work, paragraph is a too complex structure to just create it like that. What you need to do is either write a custom step definition that creates it, or since you also want to test the process of creating such a paragraph, you need to create the entity yourself, step by step. Log in as an editor with enough permissions, go to node/add/.., fill out all the fields you want and then save

Answer (score 2):

I needed something similar so I implemented a context for paragraph support.

Install using `composer require miiimooo/behat-tools`

The follow the installation and usage here: https://github.com/miiimooo/behat-tools

In your feature you can then write:

```
Feature: Content
  @api
  Scenario: Paragraph creation through Drupal 8 API

    Given a "my_paragraph_type" paragraph named "my_arbitrary_name":
      | title             | Lorem ipsum |

    Given I am viewing a "page" content:
      | title            | Dolor sed         |
      | field_paragraphs | my_arbitrary_name |
```